# Build fails if number of tables increase in Liferay service

Tags: sql-server, liferay, liferay-6

My client gave to me a database with approximately 120 tables. I have to build the service and write all these tables to `service.xml`. But whenever I tried to do this no error is display on console but build operation fails. I know that this problem arise because of large of number tables.  When I used to build operation with less number of tables then build operation work smoothly.

All tables already created I have to just build and connect with the existing database. I am modifying `hibernate-spring.xml` and also `service.properties` file to command to my build operation that do not create new tables in db, use the existing one.
ERROR:  D:\liferayWorksapce\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\build-common-plugin.xml:274: Service Builder generated exceptions
- sql server express 2008 r2
- liferay 6.1
- RAM: 4GB

Answer (score 1):

"build" in servicebuilder *does not* create any tables in the database - they only get created upon deployment. Therefor your problem can't really be related to the actual database.

For some information on how to interface existing tables to servicebuilder code, you find a lot when you search for "legacy databases", e.g. [Sten's blog article](https://www.liferay.com/de/web/sten.martinez/blog/-/blogs/using-a-legacy-db-with-service-builder) about the matter.

Your last comment reminded me of a limitation: [You can't have Entities containing "Error" or "Package" in their name](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-27710), because they mess up with the build process - it's triggering the error handling. Please vote up that issue.

Comment: but if less number of entity in service builder then ok if I increase then tables one by one even after some addition it gives me error. Olaf sir if you have any suggestion then please forward to me. Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: please add some more information about the actual error message to your question. Also, if it's a single table that you add, what's its name? Maybe there's just some encoding issue or similar. However, please add more detail to your question to help you figure out what the underlying problem is.

Comment: Because of this table I found error may be, I also modified build-common-plugin.xml and it is working and still I have to add some more tables.

Comment: <entity name="SB_ErrorCodes" local-service="true" remote-service="false" table="ErrorCodes">
  <column name="ErrorCode" type="int" primary="true" />
  <column name="ErrorDesc" type="String" />
  <column name="ObjectType" type="String" />
  <column name="ObjectId" type="int" />
 </entity>

Comment: Olaf sir would you like to just check what is the problem in this tabl.

Comment: There you are. Sorry that I didn't remember that limitation earlier - added the missing piece to my answer